# How to ignore my logical deleted entities from with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I have a structure of cart that contains orders that contains order items that contains order sub items. All this structure also work with logical delete. I have on each level a data delete property. I use Entity Framework 6.2.4

So I have C-O-OI-OSI

Here is my code to get my cart with all the structure:

```
            var cart = Context.Cart
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Include(y => y.Orders.Select(z => z.OrderItems.Select(x => x.OrderSubItems)))
                .SingleOrDefault(y => y.Code == cartCode);
```

Then to remove all my deleted element I do this loop:

```
            foreach (var order in cart.Orders)
            {
                if (order.DateDelete != null)
                {
                    Context.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Detached;
                    cart.Orders.Remove(order);
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var orderItem in order.OrderItems)
                    {
                        if (orderItem.DateDelete != null)
                        {
                            Context.Entry(orderItem).State = EntityState.Detached;
                            order.OrderItems.Remove(orderItem);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            foreach (var orderSubItem in orderItem.OrderSubItems)
                            {
                                if (orderSubItem.DateDelete != null)
                                {
                                    Context.Entry(orderSubItem).State = EntityState.Detached;
                                    orderItem.OrderSubItems.Remove(orderSubItem);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

First, yes I get an exception because I'm modifying the collection of my foreach loop. so I already changed all this to a simple for classic loop.

Now my question is: Is it possible to perform this in one single nice LINQ query. I tried many things but I have nothing to post here that work a minimum.

Let me explain differently what I want:

```
                var cart = Context.Cart
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .Include(y => y.Orders) // where DateDelete == null
                    .Include(y => y.Orders.Select(z => z.OrderItems)) // where DateDelete == null
                    .Include(y => y.Orders.Select(z => z.OrderItems.Select(x => x.OrderSubItems))) // where DateDelete == null
                    .SingleOrDefault(y => y.Code == cartCode);
```

And I also tried this:

[image]

Comment: I don't want to do cascading delete on database. I want to get my collection ignoring the logical deleted one. I use logical delete because I don't want to delete them for real.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Context`, in the `OnModelCreating` method:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<YourClass>().HasQueryFilter(p => !p.IsDeleted);
```

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:
You can use Load() instead of Include(). Then your code will look like this:

```
var cart = Context.Cart
            .AsNoTracking()
            .SingleOrDefault(y => y.Code == cartCode);

Context.Entry(cart).Collection(u=>u.Orders).Query().Where(x=>x.DateDelete == null).Load();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data - here is the documentation for loading related entities because it does not work for entities that are "Lazy Loaded".

Comment: You cannot use any instruction in .Include with EF6. System.ArgumentException: 'The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.